# Is there a way to customize spacing between icons for android bottom navigation view?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to create a bottom nav bar that will look like this.

[image]

My idea is to just create a bottom nav bar with all the icons except the middle floating action bar, after which i would try to overlay the floating action bar over the nav bar. However this entails an uneven spacing between icons where there would be a large gap between the calendar icon and the heart icon. Is it possible to set this in android? As of now i cant seem to find any tutorials on how to set uneven spacings in bottom nav bar. If it is not possible is there another way to achieve this design? Hope my intent was clear. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to have the left two icons in a LinearLayout on the left, and the same for the right icons. Then inside each image just have a bit of padding so that you get the spacing between the images correct.

You could always have a blank image placeholder where the center button is going to float over, that way you can keep the spacing relative to the size of the palceholder.

Comment: So we do away with the bottom nav bar ?